# c++: strcpy not working with char array

Tags: c++, string, sorting, strcpy, names

I'm sorting an array of names and my IDE is giving me "no matching function for call to 'strcpy'.
Here are the values I set up:

```
char Names [MaxNames] [MaxCharsPerName + 1];
const int MaxNames          (20);
const int MaxCharsPerName   (15);
```

Here is my function

```
void SortNames (const char Names[][MaxCharsPerName + 1], int NumNames)
{
int     i;
int     NumElements;
bool    Sorted;
char    Temp; // size 15?

NumElements = NumNames;
do  {
    Sorted = true;
    NumElements--;
    for (i = 0; i < NumNames; i++)
        {
         
            if(Names[i-1] > Names[i]){
                strcpy(Temp, Names[i]);
                strcpy(Names[i], Names[i+1]);
                strcpy(Names[i+1], Temp);

            }
        }
    
} while (!Sorted);
```

Do I have to use a reference or something?

Oh and these are at the top:

## include

```
 using namespace std;
 #include "Constants.h"
 #include "Functions.h"
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: If you are using C++, rather move over to using `std::string` for strings instead of `char []`, `char []` is the C way of doing things. Then refer to the answer of @andreas-dm below.

Answer (score 4):

```
char Temp; // size 15?
```

`Temp` is a `char` and `strcpy` expects a `char *`(and compiler will give a *compilation error* in your case).

Use a `char` array instead-

```
char Temp[MaxCharsPerName + 1]; // any desired size but reserve place for '\0'
```

And then pass it to `strcpy`.

Comment: Oh yeah. Well, I set it up like that and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @CalebLawrence You get same error after making changes ?

Comment: I do, yeah. It looks like the first line strcpy(Temp, Names[i]); works but the others don't. Maybe it's a problem with the arrays.

Comment: @CalebLawrence You mean in other part of code now shown here or in these calls .

Comment: In these calls. I call it three times in the above code and I'm only getting errors on the bottom two.

Comment: @CalebLawrence Problem must be because of `Name` is `const char [][]`  and _as you copy to it compiler is giving problem_ . Try removing `const` in function parameter list .

Comment: Oh yeah that let it pass. Thank you!!

Comment: @CalebLawrencen Welcome :)

Comment: @CalebLawrence I think the bug you are now seeing is because you are copying from beyond the end of your "names" list.
`Names[i+1]` is going to go beyond the end of your list when `i = NumNames - 1` (i.e. the last iteration of your loop).
if you change your for loop to `for (i = 0; i < NumNames - 1; i++)`, it should then get rid of your error

Comment: also the `Names[i-1]` is a worry. And you should be using `strcmp` to compare your strings (right now you are just comparing the pointers to the strings)

Comment: @GrantPeters Ohh nice , I just missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorting an array of names could be done much easier:

```
vector<string> names;
// ... 
sort(begin(names), end(names), less<string>());
for (const auto& name : names) cout << name << '\n';
```